# IIS failover Clusters?

Tags: iis, windows-server, cluster, failover, clustering

I'm new to servers and stuff(I'm a programmer not a server guy) and I have a question about IIS failover clustering. I have two IIS servers up and running, and they're identical. I want to set up the servers as a failover cluster. I want to set it up so that Server A is the main server and Server B is a backup. If Server A fails, would a failover cluster take care of the shift from Server A to B? Would it maintain user sessions, or do I need to implement NLB(s) or sticky sessions? Thanks kind people of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

In order to preserve sessions, you will have to enable a session-persistence mechanism that is hosted off the failed server, so you need to [use](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736497(v=ws.10).aspx) either a remote `SQLServer` [database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753897(v=ws.10).aspx) or an `StateServer` (an [ASP Session State server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732412(v=ws.10).aspx)). see here for the list of options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemode(v=vs.110).aspx

`INPROC` (the default mechanism) stores session in the web applications `w3wp.exe` process instance. If the site goes down, that information will not be available to the other server.

As for [Network Load Balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Load_Balancing) (NLB), it is a type of clustering called "[High Performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HPCC)", and uses both servers all the time. Fail-over clustering (called "[High Availability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-availability_cluster)") is distinct in that only one server is active at a time, and instead of monitoring the load on each server, it worries about Hello signals that tell the cluster the state of the primary node.